# How to copy / clone / save YouTube watch later playlist into new playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, youtube-watch-later

How to clone export import YouTube watch later playlist into new playlist?

Comment: This works for other playlists but not for watch later https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItBTmwdFBtw